# AWS limiting policy permissions for EC2 create

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, policy

What is then most limited iam policy I can give a user to still allow them to create an EC2? They the policy doesn't need anything else, I've messed with it on and off for a day and cannot get the right combination?

Comment: What did you have so far?

Comment: At a minimum, you would need DescribeSubnets, DescribeImages and RunInstances.

Comment: @INVOKECloud i was literally starting from * and working myself down

Comment: I've messed with it on and off --> These details are what I was asking in my previous comment.

Comment: Do you wish them to launch the instance via the console, or via the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/)? The console would require more permissions to avoid errors. See also: [Amazon EC2 Resource-Level Permissions for RunInstances | AWS News Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-ec2-resource-level-permissions-for-runinstances/)

Comment: @JohnRotenstein this would all go through cli

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The minimum permissions to launch an Amazon EC2 instance via the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) is simply `RunInstances`:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "RunInstances",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ec2:RunInstances",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Using that policy, I launched an instance with this AWS CLI command:

```
aws ec2 run-instances --image-id ami-xxx --key-name my-key --security-group-id sg-xxx --instance-type t2.nano
```

**How to debug permission errors**

If you add any other parameters, then the command might fail.

For example, I added this parameter:

```
--tag-specifications 'ResourceType=instance,Tags=[{Key=Name,Value=Temp}]'
```

This failed with:

> An error occurred (UnauthorizedOperation) when calling the RunInstances operation: You are not authorized to perform this operation. Encoded authorization failure message: xxx

I then decrypted the encoded failure message (using an Admin IAM user) using:

```
aws sts decode-authorization-message --encoded-message xxx
```

This returned:

```
{
    "allowed": false,
    "explicitDeny": false,
    "matchedStatements": {
        "items": []
    },
    "failures": {
        "items": []
    },
    "context": {
        "principal": {
            "id": "AIDAxxx",
            "name": "my-user",
            "arn": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:user/my-user"
        },
        "action": "ec2:CreateTags",
        "resource": "arn:aws:ec2:ap-southeast-2:123456789012:instance/*",
        "conditions": {
            "items": [
                {
                    "key": "aws:Resource",
                    "values": {
                        "items": [
                            {
                                "value": "instance/*"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                ...
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Clearly the problem was with `ec2:CreateTags` because my command requested tags to be added to the instance. Therefore, I'd either need to add those permissions, or remove the tag parameter from the `RunInstances` command.

**Trivia**

Have you ever wondered why the command is called `RunInstances` rather than `LaunchInstances` or `CreateInstances`?

(I think) it is because in the early days of Amazon EC2, there was only Instance Storage (no Amazon Elastic Block Storage (EBS)). Therefore, it was not possible to Stop an instance, since this would lose the disk contents and the instance could not be Started again. Thus, the commands were `RunInstances` and `TerminateInstances`.

These days, we can `StartInstances` and `StopInstances`. However, the old terminology of `RunInstances` remains, which is always a bit confusing for new users since it is not obvious whether it means *launch* or *start*.

Comment: Accepted and plus one to you sir, thanks. Also love the trivia, lmao